# Syntax for BigInteger division and multiplication with decimals, in C#

Tags: c#, ethereum, biginteger

If I have a `BigInteger` with a value of `1234567891234567891234`, and I need to convert it into a `decimal` with 7 decimal points (essentially, `myBigIntVal / Math.Pow(10, 7)`, what would the syntax in C# be?

Similarly, if I have a `decimal` with value `0.07`, how would I convert it into a `BigInteger` , something along the lines of `myDecimalVal * Math.Pow(10,9)` (move decimal 9 places to the rigt).

Comment: For the first part, try `((decimal)bigInteger) / 1E7M`

Comment: `(BigInteger)(myDecimalVal * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, 9));` for the second part.

Comment: `new BigInteger(myDecimalVal * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, 9))` for the second.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is it possible to parameterize that, so i can make the "7" part dynamic?

Comment: Yes, use the Math.Pow you used.